# QR code object doesn't display encoded value when passed from a .net application

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I have a PDF template with form fields in Adobe Acrobat that has a barcode object set to QR code. There is a hidden textbox that contains the information the QR object is supposed to encode-in my case it is a shortened URL that will change depending on the item name. When I edit the PDF and manually set the hidden textbox to the URL, the QR code updates just fine and directs to the proper site. However, the QR object will not update and display correctly when I pass the URL into the textbox through a vb.net application. It's passing the same value as what I manually entered and I even set the form field manually in the application just in case there was a discrepancy in the value I was retrieving from SQL. The QR code still will not update and displays only the textbox's field name.

I have not been able to find any answers online that deals with this kind of problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: 99% of all users of your application will have Javascript turned off anyway, whether you get it working in some specific case. Meaning everything you do will be worthless. If you create the PDF ahead of time and inject the QR code, then you would have no issue. There is **no way** I would ever turn on Javascript in a PDF, you should not either and in fact no one should.

Comment: @KevinBrown I'm not using JS in the PDF and the PDF is created ahead of time. The issue is due to Adobe Reader and other PDF-reading software not having extended reader rights that Acrobat requires to change the barcode object display.